# Strip Keywords with certain length from string

Tags: php

I have a good working code to strip keywords from a text string $meta, but am wondering how I can remove words shorter than 5 letters from the result $keywords.

```
preg_match_all("/\b((?:[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b|\b((?:[a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b/u", $meta, $matches);
$keywords = implode(",",$matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use array_filter function

```
$keywords = array_filter($matches[0], function{ return strlen($x) >= 5; }); 
$keywords = implode(",",$keywords );
```

Comment: Works great, rewrote the function separately.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can `loop` through your array and add data to `new array` if your `criteria` match.

```
$result = array();
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
      if(strlen($keyword)>5){
          $result[] = $keyword;
       }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Always add explanations to answers.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thanks for your suggestion, i have made some changes.